# simple .htaccess not working - stuck in infinite loop - could this be a server config issue?

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following code in a htaccess redirect that I copied from another site which is working absolutely fine. Can anyone see any problems with this?

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site-url.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site-url.com/$1 [R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 

    </IfModule>
```

So basically I am redirecting from http://site-url.com to http://www.site-url.com and then if not https I am redirecting to https.

The provider of the servers say they don't support code which is fair enough but I have tried everything and no matter what the site gets stuck in an infinite loop. It seems like the server isnt acknowledging the

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
```

but I have also tried this with

```
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
```

And get the same problem.

Does anyone have a suggestion or could this be a configuration problem with the server? If so could anyone give an indication of what it may be?

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} != on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site-url.com$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I believe the problem you are experiencing, based on my limited knowledge of mod_rewrite, is that you are redirecting to `http://www.site-url.com/whatever` with the first rule and the second one is making it `https://site-url.com/whatever` so when you get back to the page it is going, "hmm..that's not www.site-url.com let's fix it" and you are back to `http://www.site-url.com/whatever`.  I don't think the first rule is changing the value of `%{HTTP_HOST}` which the second rule is counting on, but again I'm not the supreme expert by a long shot, but I hope my version does what you need.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I am more bothered about the second rule - I basically need to redirect the whole site to https and just using the second rule alone also results in a loop

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is two-fold.

First, your first rule is redirecting to `http://`. Second, your first rule is missing a `L`. Together, they create a situation where when you request `http://site-url.com/something`, the first rule gets applied and the request is marked as redirect to `http://www.site-url.com/something`. But without the `L` flag, the second rule immediately gets processed and gets applied (since it's not HTTPS) and thus it supercedes the redirect target of the first rule, and it redirects you to `https://site-url.com/something`.

So, the browser requests `https://site-url.com/something` and immediately, the first rule gets applied and redirects you back to `http://www.site-url.com/something`, then the second rule gets applied because there's no `L` flag, etc. etc. infinite loop.

Solution, add a `L` and `https` to your rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site-url.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site-url.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I should have mentioned that I have tried this 'RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]' on its own and that results in an infinite loop also - even without the first rule